# Remove WorkSpace Files

Tags: r, dataframe

```
a1 = 1
a2 = 2
bfrog = 5
btart = 9
c = 0

rm(list = ls(pattern = "^a"))
rm(list = ls(pattern = "^b"))
```

This works and but I wonder why this does not work: `rm(list = ls(pattern = "^a" | pattern = "^b"))`

Comment: Try `rm(list = ls(pattern = "^[ab]"))`

Comment: Do you mean `rm(list = ls(pattern = "^a|^b"))`?

Comment: @I am just wondering why this receives minus votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place it inside the pattern string:

`ls(pattern = "^a|^b")`

`pattern` requires a regular expression and these can be separated by `|`

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed code `rm(list = ls(pattern = "^a" | pattern = "^b"))` does not work because you specify multiple arguments with the same name `pattern`.

Instead you should use `regex` to implement the 'or' using:

```
rm(list = ls(pattern = "^[ab]"))
```

The crucial part here is:

```
ls(pattern = "^[ab]")
```

Which is regex for: Anything that starts with (`^`) one of the things (`[]`) which is an `a` or a `b`.

See also:

```
grepl("^[ab]", c("astart", "bstart", "dstart"))
```

Returns:

```
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```